# How to change the bibliography style to APA for the following research format? Here it is showing [1] and I want to make it as superscript 1

Tags: bibliographies, ieee-style, bibliographystyle

```
\documentclass[12pt]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\begin{document}
\title{LIGO Gravitational Wave Detector}
\author{jhkjhksdjklfjdslkjf}
\maketitle 
\section{Acknowledgements}
LIGO stands for Laser Interferometer Gravitational Wave Detector that detects gravitational waves from the galaxies and cluster of galaxies ~\cite{Dalf}.
\begin{thebibliography}{}
\bibitem{Dalf}
Martynov D V., Hall ED, Abbott BP, et al. Sensitivity of the Advanced LIGO detectors at the beginning of gravitational wave astronomy. Phys Rev D. 2016;93(11). doi:10.1103/PhysRevD.93.112004
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the best document you can find for you issue, https://www-sop.inria.fr/miaou/latex/ttb_en.pdf

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

> [The citation call-out] is showing `[1]` and I want to make it as superscript `1`.

I suggest you load the [natbib](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/) citation management package with the option `super`:

```
\usepackage[super]{natbib}
```